Are "c'est le moment" and "il est temps" largely interchangeable?
There's a lot of discussion comparing "c'est l'heure" and "il est temps" but I haven't found much on the difference between "c'est le moment" and "il est temps". I find it interesting how these two phrases are used in different translations of the same Bible passages.

1 Pierre 4:17
Car c'est le moment où le jugement va commencer par la maison de Dieu. Or, si c'est par nous qu'il commence, quelle sera la fin de ceux qui n'obéissent pas à l'Evangile de Dieu? (Louis Segond's translation)
Car il est temps que le jugement commence par la maison de Dieu; or [s'il commence] premièrement par nous, quelle sera la fin de ceux qui n'obéissent point à l'Evangile de Dieu? (David Martin's version)
Psaumes 119:126
Il est temps que l'Éternel agisse: ils ont annulé ta loi. (Bible Darby en français)
SEIGNEUR, c’est le moment de faire quelque chose ! On désobéit à ta loi ! (Parole de Vie)
Il est temps que l'Eternel agisse:Ils transgressent ta loi. (Nouvelle Edition de Genève)
C’est le moment d’agir, ô Eternel, car on viole ta Loi ! (La Bible du Semeur)
Il est temps d’agir pour toi, Eternel, car on viole ta loi. (Segond 21)
Il est temps que l’Éternel agisse: Ils transgressent ta loi. (Louis Segond's translation)


Oui, je dirais qu'il n'y a qu'une différence de style, mais pas de sens.

Jerome's Vulgata opted for "Quoniam tempus est" in Peter I and for "Tempus faciendi, Domine" in Psalm 119(118).

As your examples show, they are largely interchangeable but if you look for a slight difference, I'd say c'est le moment means now is precisely the right time to do something, it was too early before and it will be too late after while il est temps is more like we've spent enough time doing something and we should think about doing something else from now.

Tout à fait, il est temps que tu te taises avec toutes tes phrases subordonnées ; ce n'est pas le moment. ( :
